# Растолкуйте на RU языке про исключения HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net

Как правильно обрабатывать исключения `HttpClient` ?

Если я правильно понимаю, тут нет статусов как у [WebRequest и WebResponse](https://metanit.com/sharp/net/2.4.php)

Или есть какой то `Status` в `HttpRequestException.InnerException`, но его так просто не получить(

По тексту `HttpRequestException.Message` что ли обрабатывать) ?

Есть тут ещё какой то `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();`

Но в моём коде до него даже дело не доходит)

```
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(hre.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сам `HttpClient` нуже для того, чтобы (к примеру) отправить запрос и получить ответ например так: `HttpResponseMessage response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");`. А вот у `HttpResponseMessage` уже есть `StatusCode`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц так если я получаю исключение уже на моменте отправки запроса ?

Comment: @ヒミコ [А так есть ?](http://prntscr.com/q7ltq5) UPD: Куда то делось сообщение от ヒミコ

Comment: @Vipz, У вас проблема не с `HttpClient`'ом, а с тем, что данный веб сайт заблокирован это раз, и два, можете попробовать написать расширение [`SNI`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) для `TLS`, тогда не будет проблем с доступом.

Comment: @ヒミコ т.е. кроме таких заблокированных сайтов,  никакие другие неведомые силы не могут вызвать это исключение ?

Comment: @Vipz, в вашем случае да, в других случаях может быть что-то еще, к примеру нарушение работы DNS, или еще что.

Comment: @ヒミコ Так вот как все эти исключения разобрать для разработки ? я наверно про это вопрос и задавал) Или мне просто ждать пока не появится необработанное исключение и только потом его обрабатывать ? Вы не пылите если что - я новичок и хватало библиотеки типа xNet - там было куда проще.

Comment: А все зависит от того, что вы дальше хотите сделать. Если вам нужен просто вывод сообщения об ошибки/логирование или еще что, то просто делайте try/catch(Exeption e). Все, вам этого хватит за глаза. То есть вот [такой код](https://pastebin.com/1SGahafR) в итоге получится, дальше просто проверяйте на NULL, если что то он вернет, то смело можете обрабатывать эти данные, null - данные по тем или иным причинам к нам не поступили (причины читаем в логе (например)).

Comment: Если же вам надо обработать конкретный код (например помню мы для CloudFlare писали обход и там если выдавал вроде 403, то надо было формировать определенный js код), то и обрабатывайте его. То есть в коде, что я дал выше пишете не `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)`, а например `if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Понял вас, спасибо! Получается что `яндекс / google` роботы с такими же проблемами встречаются типа CloudFlare ? Или для них какие то другие двери открыты ?

Comment: Поисковые роботы это совершенно другая история)) Они имеют уйму алгоритмов по разбору того или иного контента, некоторые имеют вовсе договоренности среди компаний (я на 100% уверен, что CloudFlare пропускает часть поисковых ботов на сайты).

Comment: ну контент да) я про доступы к сайтам.

Comment: Я вам уже говорил в предыдущем вопросе, что защиту, которая блокирует доступ к сайту - ставят единицы, 99% сайтов вам выдадут все "публичное" простым get запросом, даже без заголовков и "печенек". Так что такие "поисковые" боты легко доберутся до всего, что не заблокировано. Всякие CloudFlare - это защиты от ддос атак и они да, могут повлиять на отправку get запроса, но как я уже говорит, я уверен, что у них есть "белый" список для таких поисковиков, ибо они не являются ддос атакой, а их блок привлечет к потере аудитории сайта (что сами понимаете, не выгодно).